# Want to run a query multiple times using a for loop and add each result into a dictionary. This code only execute once even as it loops through

Tags: python, sql, pandas, random, amazon-redshift

I have a query that take a random sample of records. I want to do this multiple times and add each result into a dictionary, which I will concat into a pandas DataFrame later. This code only execute once even as it loops through.

```
cursor.execute("select record1, record2 from table order by random() limit 1000")

d = {}
for x in range(10):
    d[x] = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.fetchall()` doesn't execute the query, it just fetches the remaining results from the query that was already executed by `cursor.execute()`. The first iteration of the loop fetches everything, so the other 9 iterations have nothing left to fetch and you get empty dataframes.

You need to move the `cursor.execute()` call into the loop.

```
d = {}
for x in range(10):
    cursor.execute("select record1, record2 from table order by random() limit 1000")
    d[x] = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

Note that there will likely be overlap between the records in each dataframe. If you don't want that, you should do a single query for 10,000 records, and then slice them into dataframes for each block of 1,000.

```
cursor.execute("select record1, record2 from table order by random() limit 10000")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
d = {}
for x in range(0,10000,1000):
    d[x/1000] = pd.DataFrame(rows[x:x+1000])
```